# How to open up a given file's properties window in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, file, properties

Lets say I have the path to a file and I want to show a files property window. What I mean by property window is:

Properties window:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbBNh.png]

I want to be able to open that window or a universal Java Swing window using java to show and be able to edit the file's attributes like the properties window in the image can?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to open the Properties Window (built into the Operating System) in Java, because the Properties Window will vary per OS, and will not make it friendly for all Operating Systems. Java is loaded with many methods that already can give you a head start on making one similar using Swing. As a start, here are some methods that may be helpful:

`File.getAbsolutePath` -> Returns the Absolute Path of the File

`Files.getAttribute` -> Returns a FileTime Object which contains the creation time of the File.

`File.lastModified` -> Returns last modified date of File.

I strongly suggest you should do some research first before asking.